# Bash substitution within lerna exec not working

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, unix, lerna

I have this command that prints out all the folder names of all the packages within a lerna project.

```
lerna exec -- node -e 'console.log(path.basename(process.cwd()))'
```

I have this command that should replace the name of every lerna package's name within package.json with the name of the folder. It uses substitution.

```
lerna exec -- json -I -f ./package.json -e 'this.name = "@reggi/'`node -e 'console.log(path.basename(__dirname))'`'"'
```

The issue is that it names the packages the name of the folder containing the entire lerna package.

This does the same thing. It logs the name of the parent lerna package over and over.

```
lerna exec -- echo `node -e 'console.log(path.basename(process.cwd()))'`
```

Bash substitution is not allowing the command on the right side of `exec` to run within it's own process, it's compiling before it get's a chance to run it.

How can I use substitution in bash and not save the output of the argument, to allow the runtime to process the new value of the substitution?

Answer (score -1):

A small script will ensure that all your work is done in the same process:

```
#!/bin/bash
WD=`pwd`
PACKAGE=@reggi/`basename "$WD"`
json -I -f package.json -e "this.name=\"$PACKAGE\""
```

make sure that it's executable and on your path, then

```
lerna exec rename.sh
```

Comment: You need to name the bash file "rename.sh" and make sure that it's executable and on your path.

Comment: Its important to say that you need this file to be located in each package. the OP spoke about running one command without creating a `rename.sh` in every package